# How to assign number for a repeating pattern

Tags: sed, awk, grep, design-patterns

I am doing some calculations using gaussian. From the gaussian output file, I need to extract the input structure information. The output file contains more than 800 structure coordinates. What I did so far is, collect all the input coordinates using some combinations of the `grep`, `awk` and `sed` commands, like so:

```
grep -A 7 "Input orientation:" test.log | grep -A 5 "C" | awk '/C/{print "structure number"}1' | sed '/--/d' > test.out
```

This helped me to `grep` all the input coordinates and insert a line with "structure number". So now  I have a file that contains a pattern which is being repeated in a regular fashion.  The file is like the following:

> structure Number
>
> 4.176801   -0.044096    2.253823
>
> 2.994556    0.097622    2.356678
>
> 5.060174   -0.115257    3.342200
>
> structure Number
>
> 4.180919   -0.044664    2.251182
>
> 3.002927    0.098946    2.359346
>
> 5.037811   -0.103410    3.389953

Here, "Structure number" is being repeated. I want to write a number like "structure number:1", "structure number 2" in increasing order.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar at all with a program called gaussian, so I have no clue what the original input looked like. If someone posts an example I might be able to give an even shorter solution.

However, as far as I got it the OP is contented with the output of his/her code besided that he/she wants to append an increasing number to the lines inserted with `awk`.

This can be achieved with the following line (adjusting the OP's code):

```sh
grep -A 7 "Input orientation:" test.log | grep -A 5 "C" | awk '/C/{print "structure number"++i}1' | sed '/--/d' > test.out
```

**Addendum:**

Even without knowing the actual input, I am sure that one can at least get rid of the `sed` command leaving that piece of work to `awk`. Also, there is no need to quote a single character grep pattern:

```sh
grep -A 7 "Input orientation:" test.log | grep -A 5 C | awk '/C/{print "structure number"++i}!/--/' > test.out
```

I am not sure since I cannot test, but it should be possible to let `awk` do the `grep`'s work, too. As a first guess I would try the following:

```sh
awk '/Input orientation:/{li=7}!li{next}{--li}/C/{print "structure number"++i;lc=5}!lc{next}{--lc}!/--/' test.log > test.out
```

While this might be a little bit longer in code it is an `awk`-only solution doing all the work in one process. If I had input to test with, I might come up with a shorter solution.